# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'

Tags: swift, swift2, nsurl

Here is a fun issue I'm running into after updating to `Swift 2.0`

The error is on the `if let url = URL.absoluteString` line

```
func myFormatCompanyMessageText(attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString) -> NSMutableAttributedString
{
    // Define text font
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Montserrat-Light", size: 17)!, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

    return attributedString
}

func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    if let url = URL.absoluteString {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            VPMainViewController.showCompanyMessageWebView(url)
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Did you lookup the documentation for the `absoluteString` method? Does it return an optional??

Comment: Just looked it up. No it doesn't return an optional, but `relativeString` is

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you can't use an `if let` because it's totally unnecessary. You don't have any optionals to unwrap: `URL` is not optional, and the `absoluteString` property isn't optional either. `if let` is used exclusively to unwrap optionals. If you want to create a new constant named `url`, just do it:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    let url = URL.absoluteString
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        VPMainViewController.showCompanyMessageWebView(url)
    }
    return false
}
```

However, sidenote: having a parameter named `URL` and a local constant named `url` is mighty confusing. You might be better off like this:

```
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWithURL URL: NSURL, inRange characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        VPMainViewController.showCompanyMessageWebView(URL.absoluteString)
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: can we use guard here?

Comment: @iPhone6 No, for the same reason you can't use `if let`: because `URL.absoluteString` *always* succeeds. There's nothing to guard against--`absoluteString` is non-optional and will never be `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

`absoluteString` isn't an optional value, its just a String. You can check if the URL variable is nil

```
if let url = yourURLVariable {
    // do your textView function
} else {
    // handle nil url
}
```

Comment: `URL: NSURL` is not an optional, it cannot be nil.

Comment: That's meant to be outside his textView function, will edit for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Note: with reference to the question

Guard or if conditions are used to make sure if the values is not present it should not crash. but the function argument makes sure (URL: NSURL) will come, or any scenario which makes sure the values do come there no need to check with if let or guard statement. That is what compiler is educating developer. try removing the if let or guard statement in such case it should work