# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CGFloat'

Tags: ios, swift

There is two error i am stuck .I am getting this error when i open my project in new xcode 8 swift 3.0 I dont know how to rectify this error. I have solve some others bugs. But struck here in this line for the above mentioned error.

```
 func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
        keyboardHasBeenShown = true

        guard let userInfo = (notification as NSNotification).userInfo else {return}
        guard let endKeyBoardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue.minY else {return}

        if tmpContentViewFrameOrigin == nil {
        tmpContentViewFrameOrigin = self.contentView.frame.origin
        }

        if tmpCircleViewFrameOrigin == nil {
        tmpCircleViewFrameOrigin = self.circleBG.frame.origin
        }

        var newContentViewFrameY = self.contentView.frame.maxY - endKeyBoardFrame
        if newContentViewFrameY < 0 {
            newContentViewFrameY = 0
        }
        let newBallViewFrameY = self.circleBG.frame.origin.y - newContentViewFrameY
        self.contentView.frame.origin.y -= newContentViewFrameY
        self.circleBG.frame.origin.y = newBallViewFrameY
    }
```

In this above method :

**My error is in below line :**

```
guard let endKeyBoardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as AnyObject).cgRectValue.minY else {return}
```

**error :**

```
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'CGFloat'
```

Second error in this below method :

```
open func showCustom(_ title: String, subTitle: String, color: UIColor, icon: UIImage, closeButtonTitle:String?=nil, duration:TimeInterval=0.0, colorStyle: UInt=SCLAlertViewStyle.success.defaultColorInt, colorTextButton: UInt=0xFFFFFF, circleIconImage: UIImage? = nil, animationStyle: SCLAnimationStyle = .topToBottom) -> SCLAlertViewResponder {


        var red: CGFloat = 0, green: CGFloat = 0, blue: CGFloat = 0, alpha: CGFloat = 0

        color.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)

        var colorAsUInt32 : UInt32 = 0
        colorAsUInt32 += UInt32(red * 255.0) << 16 + UInt32(green * 255.0) << 8 + UInt32(blue * 255.0)

        let colorAsUInt = UInt(colorAsUInt32)

        return showTitle(title, subTitle: subTitle, duration: duration, completeText:closeButtonTitle, style: .success, colorStyle: colorAsUInt, colorTextButton: colorTextButton, circleIconImage: icon, animationStyle: animationStyle)
    }
```

**Error in this line :**

```
 colorAsUInt32 += UInt32(red * 255.0) << 16 + UInt32(green * 255.0) << 8 + UInt32(blue * 255.0)
```

**Error :**

**Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768274/initializer-for-conditional-binding-must-have-optional-type-not-string)

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25451001/getting-keyboard-size-from-userinfo-in-swift for Swift 2+3 code to get the keyboard size from a notification.

Comment: Please do not post two completely unrelated problems in one question.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, Most errors i have resolved. This two only not able to solve. And for my second error, Not able to indentify

Answer (score 1):

Need add questions mark:

```
guard let endKeyBoardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? AnyObject).cgRectValue.minY else {return}

colorAsUInt32 += UInt32(red * 255.0) << 16
colorAsUInt32 += UInt32(green * 255.0) << 8
colorAsUInt32 += UInt32(blue * 255.0)
```

Comment: @mack break up the expression.

Comment: i am new to ios before 5 days only. This project is struck with my old developer. So i dont know how to make a break up experssion for this.

Comment: @mack consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions. colorAsUInt32 += UInt32(red * 255.0) << 16, colorAsUInt32 += UInt32(green * 255.0) << 8 and so on.

Comment: If i do like this ` colorAsUInt32 += UInt32(red * 255.0) << 16
         colorAsUInt32 += UInt32(green * 255.0) << 8
         colorAsUInt32 += UInt32(blue * 255.0)` Then how i will make a plus operator for this 3 line ?

Comment: plus for colorAsUInt32.

Comment: Please i am not getting that. Please help me to solve